# str.find() = TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' ..?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, find, typeerror

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.title("Caeser Cipher Program")
master.geometry("300x200")

frame1 = Frame(master)
frame2 = Frame(master)
frame3 = Frame(master)
frame4 = Frame(master)
frame5 = Frame(master)
frame6 = Frame(master)


global encryptedText
global file
global shiftKey
file = ""
encryptedText = ""
removeSpaces = ""
def Start():
    frame1.grid()
    Question = Label(frame1, text = "Would you like to encrypt or decrypt a statement?\n\n\n")
    Question.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    ButtonPlace1 = Button(frame1, text = "Encrypt", command = EncryptChosen)
    ButtonPlace2 = Button(frame1, text = "Decrypt", command = decrypt_command)
    ButtonPlace1.place(x = 75, y = 50, anchor = "c")
    ButtonPlace2.place(x = 175, y = 50, anchor = "c")

def EncryptChosen():
 frame1.destroy()
 frame2.grid()
 Question = Label(frame2, text = "What would you like to shift it by?\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n ")
 ButtonPlace3 = Entry(frame2)
 def SubmitEncryptionKey():
         shiftKey = ButtonPlace3.get()
         frame2.destroy()
         frame3.grid()
         Question = Label(frame3, text = "What would you like it to say?\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n" )
         ButtonPlace5 = Entry(frame3)
         def SubmitText():
            file = ButtonPlace5.get()
            frame3.destroy()
            frame4.grid()
            Question = Label(frame4, text = "Would you like to remove spaces?\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n")
            Question.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
            def doRemoveSpaces():
                    global spacesStatement
                    global removeSpaces
                    spacesStatement = "spaces will be removed"
                    removeSpaces = "True"
                    ReadyToEncrypt()
            ButtonPlace7 = Button(frame4, text = "Yes", command = doRemoveSpaces)
            def doNotRemoveSpaces():
                    global spacesStatement
                    global removeSpaces
                    spacesStatement = "spaces will not be removed"
                    removeSpaces = "False"
                    ReadyToEncrypt()
            ButtonPlace8 = Button(frame4, text = "No", command = doNotRemoveSpaces)
            def ReadyToEncrypt():
                    frame4.destroy()
                    frame5.grid()
                    Question = Label(frame5, text = file + "\n will be encrypted by " + shiftKey + " and \n" + spacesStatement + ".\t\t\t\n\n\n\n")
                    Question.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
                    def encryptSetup():

                            def encrypt(character):
                                alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
                                character = character.lower()
                                if character.isalpha():
                                    position = str(alphabet).find(character) + shiftKey
                                    if position > 25:
                                        position -= 26 
                                    return alphabet[position]
                                else:
                                    return character

                            for line in file:
                              for c in line:
                                global encryptedText
                                encryptedText = encryptedText + encrypt(c)

                            if removeSpaces == "True":
                               encryptedText = encryptedText.replace(" ","")
                            frame5.destroy()
                            frame6.grid()
                            Question = Label(frame6, text = "Here is your encrypted message: \n" + encryptedText)
                            Question.grid(row = 0, column = 1)    

                    ButtonPlace9 = Button(frame5, text = "Encrypt!", command = encryptSetup)
                    ButtonPlace9.place(x=175,y=50)
            ButtonPlace7.place(x = 75, y = 50, anchor = "c")
            ButtonPlace8.place(x = 175, y = 50, anchor = "c")
         ButtonPlace6 = Button(frame3, text = "Submit", command = SubmitText)
         Question.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
         ButtonPlace5.place(x=50,y=50)
         ButtonPlace6.place(x=175,y=45)
 ButtonPlace4 = Button(frame2, text = "Submit", command = SubmitEncryptionKey)
 Question.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
 ButtonPlace3.place(x=50,y=50)
 ButtonPlace4.place(x=175,y=45)



frame1.grid()
Question = Label(frame1, text = "Would you like to encrypt or decrypt a statement?\n\n\n")
Question.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
ButtonPlace1 = Button(frame1, text = "Encrypt", command = EncryptChosen)
ButtonPlace2 = Button(frame1, text = "Decrypt", command = "")
ButtonPlace1.place(x = 75, y = 50, anchor = "c")
ButtonPlace2.place(x = 175, y = 50, anchor = "c")

master.loop()
```

This is my code for a program that allows you to encrypt or decrypt a statement in the form of a caeser cypher. So far, I have coded it so that you go through it, choose what you want it to be shifted by, what you want encrypted, and whether or not you want spaces to be removed. I haven't started working on the decryption yet. However, in the code that, after all necessary variables have been collected, actually encrypts the statement I encountered a problem. I created a string called 'alphabet' that stores the entire alphabet. When the function is run through, I need to find where the character is in the alphabet so I can shift it. However, when I had done this and ran it I got an error:

```
position = alphabet.find(character) + shiftKey
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Also, when I use the for loop to run through the entire statement and encrypt it all, I encounter this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'encryptedText' referenced before assignment
```

This is a problem as essentially what I need to do is add each encrypted character to the encrypted text string but this is preventing me doing it. Please can somebody help in any way as I need to finish this project for Monday 9th March 2017.

Comment: `alphabet.find(character)` returns the position (integer) of the character. that's the problem.

Comment: What can I do to change that?

Comment: And also what about the other problem?

Comment: actually convert `shiftKey` to `int(shiftKey)` you want to add integers. other problem: you have to define variables before using them...

Comment: ok thanks it seems to be working

Comment: shiftKey is a str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alphabet.find(chr)` returns an integer, `shiftkey` is a string -- change one or the other to match.

`encrypted_text` is a local variable in its function -- the `global encrypted_text` declaration you have at the top in the global scope is useless.  `global` is meant to be used inside functions to tell Python that the variable name listed is not local to the function, and to go find it in the global scope.